# Navigate/Browse button in a webpage

Tags: java, html

I am workign on a webpage and in that I am querying a DB and getting filepath. I am able to dispaly that path from DB on my page. Now as an enhancement I wanted to add a 'Open' button next to the path being displayed. As the file would be .xml or .xsd so we can use the new window/tab of browser to open the same.
I am aware of html codes used to upload a file but don't know the code to open a file.
I tried playing with `<input type=file>` but no luck.

So can anyone help me in this.Any small pointer will be helpful.
I am not using Swings so no point of trying `JFileChooser`

Answer (score 1):

A file input is for people to upload files.

If you want to let people view files that are on the server, just use a normal link.